# Notepad++ Help: Deleting a Column?

Tags: notepad++

I have a .yml file with incorrect tabulation. This is how it looks:

```
    explosivearrow:
        spell-class: ".instant.ProjectileSpell"
        name: explosivearrow
        spell-icon: arrow
        description: Cause an explosion where an arrow lands
        cast-item: blaze_rod
        cooldown: 1
        projectile: arrow
        velocity: 0
        require-hit-entity: false
        cancel-damage: true
        remove-projectile: true
        max-distance: 30
        spells: [explode]
        cost:
            - mana 30
        str-cost: 30 mana
        str-cast-self: Shebang! Take that one!
```

This is how it NEEDS to look:

```
explosivearrow:
    spell-class: ".instant.ProjectileSpell"
    name: explosivearrow
    spell-icon: arrow
    description: Cause an explosion where an arrow lands
    cast-item: blaze_rod
    cooldown: 1
    projectile: arrow
    velocity: 0
    require-hit-entity: false
    cancel-damage: true
    remove-projectile: true
    max-distance: 30
    spells: [explode]
    cost:
        - mana 30
    str-cost: 30 mana
    str-cast-self: Shebang! Take that one!
```

So basically I need to remove the frist column of the file. I can do it manually but I don't really want to backspace 4 spaces from 1519 lines... Can anyone help me?
This is my first question, so I apologise if I did something wrong.

Comment: CTRL + A to select all, then hold SHIFT and press TAB. Should move all the lines to the left. (assuming you have notepad++ configured as 4 spaces for tab).

Comment: Ok, that helped a lot, but now all of my code attributes are red. Does this matter?

Comment: It's probably just Notepad++ formatting your source file (syntax highlighting). Is anything selected under the Language menu? They aren't displayed as red in my version of notepad++.

Comment: Ahh, I know what's going on. You need to ensure that you have spaces at the start of the line, and not TABS. According to the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235606/best-yaml-editor-for-windows-users TABs make your YAML invalid. If I do that on my editor, the complete line appears as red.

Comment: Ok, I changed my preferences to spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: Ok, I'll add this as an answer then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place your cursor to the left of `explosivearrow`, hold `SHIFT + ALT` and then hold the down arrow key. This will expand your cursor to multiple lines, so you can operate on every line at once

Comment: I know that learning how to de-tabify a region of code is important here, but I think that this multi-line cursor is a cool feature of Notepad++ and worth pointing out

Comment: Thanks! As I said I'm new, so I didn't know beforehand. Both of your answers help enormously, I hate dealing with silly tabualtion!

Comment: I didn't know about operating on multiple lines feature in Notepad++ like you mention above. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Select all lines in the document using `CTRL + A`. Then hold `SHIFT` and press `TAB` to move the lines to the left.

**Note:** This relies on Notepad++ being configured with 4 spaces for a `TAB`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7727271/1020559) having spaces before the attributes is invalid YAML and causes Notepad++ to display the lines in red.